# what does " innocent betrayed" mean?

Tags: meaning

what does "innocent betrayed" mean? 
for example in the sentence

> There is no excuse to make up for the millions of innocent betrayed.

or maybe this one is correct "innocent betrayed dead". 
What is the meaning of betrayed here?

Comment: It means innocent people, people who hadn't done anything wrong, were not involved in whatever conflict is under study, were betrayed. Nothing more subtle than that.

Comment: Please note, though, that there's a similar but not identical phrase in common use, *innocence betrayed*. It doesn't mean the same thing. Make sure you're asking about the actual phrase you saw.

Comment: "The... betrayed" is a case of an adjective being used as a noun, as in "the wounded" or "the poor".

Comment: I think it would be more common to see "... the millions of innocents betrayed", using "innocents" as the noun and "betrayed" as the modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kate Bunting said, this refers to innocent people. The sentence is equivalent to "there is no excuse to make up for the millions of innocent **people who have been** betrayed".